# Using my module both in node.js and in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, import, svg.js

Sorry if my question seems weird, but I am quite new to javascript/nodejs/react, and can't really achieve the following:

I made a module that uses **SVG.js** to generate SVG-s, and I would like to use it in different applications (in Node.js as well as in React apps). In React, I can create an SVG object with `SVG()`. If I want to create one in Node.js, then I would need to create a DOM element beforehand and pass it into `SVG()`:

```js
const window = exports.createSVGWindow();
const document = window.document;
registerWindow(window, document);
this.draw = SVG(document.documentElement);
```

For this I would need to import *svgdom* (as suggested in SVG.js), but then the React app doesn't compile, because:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in ...
```

What would be the best practice to implement my module in this case?

- I tried to use dynamical import inside my node module (inside the class constructor), but it didn't really set `this.draw` for some reason:

```js
if ( typeof process !== "undefined" &&
     process.release.name.search(/node|io.js/) !== -1) {
      // script is running in Node.js
      const createDOM = async function () {
        let exports = await import("svgdom");

        const window = exports.createSVGWindow();
        const document = window.document;
        registerWindow(window, document);
        this.draw = SVG(document.documentElement);
      };

      createDOM();
} else {
  // script is not running in Node.js
  this.draw = SVG();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly clear on what you are doing, but it is common in React to use the `useEffect` hook for your client side code.

exp:

```
const MyComponent =(props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // put your code that only is supposed to run on the client here
  })

  return (<div>Hello</div>)
}
```

`useEffect` only runs once the component has mounted to the DOM so it will not run on your server.

another option would be to do something like this:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  // client-side-only code
}
```